# (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) What does the <?> symbol do?

Tags: java, android

I'm aware this is simple, but I couldn't find a list of symbols and their meanings on the Android Developer website. Just want to know what the ? symbol means, in general, in Java; and if its meaning changes depending on case.

For example, if the meaning changes if used in (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id), as opposed to another use; I wouldn't imagine it does but I figured I'd ask in case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a wildcard. <?> is the same as <? extends Object> - any type.
The way wildcards are usually used is <? extends Foo> (any class that extends Foo) or <? super Foo> (any class that is a supertype of Foo)

Here is an example of usage of <?>:

Consider the following method, printList:

```
public static void printList(List<Object> list) {
for (Object elem : list)
System.out.println(elem + " ");
System.out.println();
}
```

The goal of printList is to print a list of any type, but it fails to achieve that goal — it prints only a list of Object instances; it cannot print List, List, List, and so on, because they are not subtypes of List. To write a generic printList method, use List<?>:

```
public static void printList(List<?> list) {
for (Object elem: list)
System.out.print(elem + " ");
System.out.println();
}
```

Because for any concrete type A, List is a subtype of List<?>, you can use printList to print a list of any type:

```
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<String> ls = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
printList(li);
printList(ls);
```

See this for more info: [Wildcards (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Generics (Updated))](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)